# Remote terminal into a ubuntu system via internet

Tags: command-line, internet, remote-access

I have this machine in a separate network which has connected to internet via NAT. My computer is connected to internet and to access that machine I use `teamviewer`.

Now I am tired of `teamviewer` and their slow `gui` which doesn't support any keyboard commands.

I need to connect to that machine only through terminal. `SSH` won't work because of the `NAT` and I don't have access to the router to setup `port-forwarding`.

So my question, is there a way to connect to that machine's terminal via internet..? Maybe a software like `teamviewer` but only with terminal..?

Both my machine and the remote machine have `Ubuntu` installed in it.

Comment: Perhaps you could use a *reverse* SSH connection, as described here: [How can I help someone (like granny) over SSH who is behind a NAT router?](https://askubuntu.com/a/48123/178692)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comment a reverse SSH connection is probably the easiest if your computer has a internet routeable IP (it seems like you're saying you do).  If you go down this route, you'll want to run it inside an infinite `while` loop, so that if the connection dies, it will start up again.

However, if your machine isn't directly on the internet (eg. have an internet routeable IP) or you don't want to allow your other computer to login to your machine, here's a couple other ideas:

- If the other router has UPnP turned on, you might be able to use a [tool](https://github.com/kaklakariada/portmapper) to send a upnp request to the router to map an external port to a port on the internal ip.
- Setup a [Tor Hidden Service](https://www.comparitech.com/blog/vpn-privacy/how-to-set-up-a-tor-hidden-service/).  This is a pretty reliable method that doesn't rely on router configurations, but it will be slower.