# What's blocking public access to Ubuntu web server?

Tags: networking, server, firewall, ufw

Backstory, Until now, I have used Ubuntu 16.04 Workstation, and now, on a new box, am playing with Ubuntu Server 16.04.3 LTS. Fast forward to setting up a LAMP stack, I cannot for the life of me figure out why I cannot access my box when I could 2 days ago.

I have assigned a static IP to my Ubuntu box and setup port forwarding (neither was nessesory beforehand).
I am using No-IP's dynamic DNS service - configured through my router.
UFW is configured to allow in Apache Full (80,443) from anywhere.

It should be working just fine dammit.. but it isn't.

The UFW log (/var/log/ufw.log) shows 1 block when I try access my public IP but seems to be IGMP related (I don't know anything about IGMP) so what do you think is going on here? Am I missing something in the setup that is usually taken care of in Ubuntu Workstation?

> Dec 26 19:31:31 ubuntu kernel: [28828.327908] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s25
>   OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01*10:13:31:a5:a0:e0*08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0
>   DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2

EDIT: Before going to Ubuntu Server, I was relying on NAT-PMP/UPnP and never touched the modem aside to get my local IP. Also noticed that Ubuntu Workstation was using the old eth0 instead of enp0s25 in Server.

Comment: That message has nothing to do with Apache, port 80 or port 443; it shows `ufw` blocking your router's attempts to find out which machines on the local network want to participate in multicast groups. Double check that the router is forwarding your public IP port 80 and 443 to the server's IP on the local LAN.

Comment: Yes, port forwarding it set up.  Previously, I was relying on NAT-PMP and UPnP and I never touched the router.

Comment: Double check. Because the message you show is unrelated.

Comment: Is apache running ? Can you connect from your local host ? LAN ?

Comment: @Panther Apache is running and accessible on LAN

Comment: That helps. If you can access it on your LAN then I presume it is an issue either with DNS or port forwarding from your router.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently my internet service provider had me on [CG-NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT). Instead of a [Reverse port tunnelling](https://askubuntu.com/a/50075/745069) solution, I just purchased a static IP.