# Limit what ssh-user can port-forward to

Tags: ssh

I'm using on Windows machine:

`plink -C -L 3333:<internal-server-ip>:80 -N -i keyfile.ppk <user>@<mydomain>`

where `<mydomain>` is an ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS with SSH and keyfile-only remote logins.

I noticed that I can actually port forward to anything behind the NAT on my network through `<mydomain>` server. I need a guide on how to limit this possibility in such a way, that `<user>` would be able to port forward only to specific `<internal-server-ip>` or group thereof?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is almost the same question as here: [How to create a restricted SSH user for port forwarding?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48129/how-to-create-a-restricted-ssh-user-for-port-forwarding)

The solution there is very comprehensive and should be also applicable for your problem.